# How do I define an array of objects in a state in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I need to initialize an array of objects in my state in react Ts.
The array should look somewhat like this

```
  addressBook[
       details{
           name:"Tom"
           mail: "xyz@g.com"
           mobile: "1111111111"
       }
   ]
```

I need to create an array of objects like this which will contain multiple contacts with their details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an interface:

```
interface Detail {
  name: string;
  mail: string;
  mobile: string;
}
```

Then in component definition:

```
const DetailPage = (): ReactElement => {
   const [details, setDetails] = useState<Detail[]>([]);

   return ( . . . );
};
```

Comment: I need to define it in a state. How would I be doing that?